# Ramda - Get one array from multiple objects

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to extract array of nodes from multiple objects using ramda.

Sample data:

```
const testData = {
  "117590": {
    "id": 117590,
    "nodes": [
      117864,
      117865,
      117866
    ]
  },
  "117591": {
    "id": 117591,
    "nodes": [
      117867,
      117868
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried to use such query: `R.pluck('nodes', testData);`
But as a result I got:

```
{"117590": [117864, 117865, 117866], "117591": [117867, 117868]}
```

How to combine all nodes in one array?
Here is my [Ramda editor link](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20testData%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22117590%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20117590%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22nodes%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20117864%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20117865%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20117866%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22117591%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20117591%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22nodes%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20117867%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20117868%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D%0A%0AR.pluck%28%27nodes%27%2C%20testData%29%3B%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1: Convert to array using R.values, and then pluck and flatten results.

Option 2: Use R.values, and then get the `nodes` and flatten using R.chain with R.prop.

```js
const { pipe, values, pluck, flatten, chain, prop } = R

const fn1 = pipe(values, pluck('nodes'), flatten)
const fn2 = pipe(values, chain(prop('nodes')))

const testData = {"117590":{"id":117590,"nodes":[117864,117865,117866]},"117591":{"id":117591,"nodes":[117867,117868]}}

console.log(fn1(testData))

console.log(fn2(testData))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Both solutions are working but could you tell me which one is more efficient? I would like to use it with large set of objects.

Comment: The 2nd one should be more efficient (less loops). I haven't profiled but it usually doesn't really matter unless you have more than 20k objects.

Answer (score 1):

Just think about it in two steps.  First get the values of the object, and then take their `node` properties.  The simplest way to get those nodes is to use `chain (prop ('node'))`.  The two steps can be combined with `pipe` or `compose`.

```js
const getNodes = pipe (values, chain(prop('nodes')))

const testData = {117590: {id: 117590, nodes: [117864, 117865, 117866]}, 117591: {id: 117591, nodes: [117867, 117868]}}

console .log (getNodes (testData))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, values, chain, prop} = R                                 </script>
```